# VS2010 merge 32 bit and 64 bit solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have 2 different visual studio solutions. one is 32 bit solution and other is 64 bit solution. Is there any way I can merge those 2 into a single solution?
can I merge .vcxproj files or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a diffmerge of the project files. They are plain xml files. That should work.

Comment: No diffmerge doesn't work completely, You have to understand the tags and then merge them manually. But yes merging works !!